# can't find DOM index of blurred object

Tags: jquery, dom, indexing

I have inputs laid out in tabular form.
When a blur event occurs, I want to get the index of the blurred element.

When I try, I always get -1 (not found).

html:

```
<div class='table'>
<div class='tr'>
   <div class='td'>
   <input type='text' class='gridInput' value='test1'>
   </div>
   <div class='td'>
   <input type='text' class='gridInput' value='test2'>
   </div>
   <div class='td'>
   <input type='text' class='gridInput' value='test2'>
   </div>   
 </div>   
 <div class='tr'>
   <div class='td'>
   <input type='text' class='gridInput' value='row2 test1'>
   </div>
   <div class='td'>
   <input type='text' class='gridInput' value='row2 test2'>
   </div>
   <div class='td'>
   <input type='text' class='gridInput' value='row2 test2'>
   </div>   
 </div>   

 <div id="result">
 </div>
 </div>

</div>
</div>
```

the script:

```
  $(document).on("blur",".gridInput",function(){    
    getIndex(this);
    }); 

function getIndex(obj){
    var ndx=$(obj).closest(".tr").index(obj);

    $("#result").html("index: "+ndx.toString());

}
```

CSS:

```
.table    { display: table }
.tr       { display: table-row }
.thead    { display: table-header-group }
.tbody    { display: table-row-group }
.tfoot    { display: table-footer-group }
.col      { display: table-column }
.colgroup { display: table-column-group }
.td       { 
      display: table-cell; 
      border:1pt solid #f2f2f2; 
      font-size:.8em;
      word-break:break-all;
}
.th       { 
        display: table-cell; 
        font-weight:bold; 
        border:1pt solid #f2f2f2; 
        font-size:.8em;
        background:#b4d234;
        position:relative;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/av2xamqt/)

Added later:

Even if I don't pass "this" I still always get 0

```
  $(document).on("blur",".gridInput",function(){    
    //getIndex(this);
    $("#result").html( $(this).index().toString() );
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj` is not a child of `.tr`, there's a `<div>` around the input. So you need to get the index of the parent of `obj`.

```js
$(document).on("blur", ".gridInput", function() {
  getIndex(this);
});

function getIndex(obj) {
  var ndx = $(obj).parent().index();
  $("#result").html("index: " + ndx.toString());
}
```

```css
.table {
  display: table
}
.tr {
  display: table-row
}
.thead {
  display: table-header-group
}
.tbody {
  display: table-row-group
}
.tfoot {
  display: table-footer-group
}
.col {
  display: table-column
}
.colgroup {
  display: table-column-group
}
.td {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1pt solid #f2f2f2;
  font-size: .8em;
  word-break: break-all;
}
.th {
  display: table-cell;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1pt solid #f2f2f2;
  font-size: .8em;
  background: #b4d234;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='table'>
  <div class='tr'>
    <div class='td'>
      <input type='text' class='gridInput' value='test1'>
    </div>
    <div class='td'>
      <input type='text' class='gridInput' value='test2'>
    </div>
    <div class='td'>
      <input type='text' class='gridInput' value='test2'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='tr'>
    <div class='td'>
      <input type='text' class='gridInput' value='row2 test1'>
    </div>
    <div class='td'>
      <input type='text' class='gridInput' value='row2 test2'>
    </div>
    <div class='td'>
      <input type='text' class='gridInput' value='row2 test2'>
    </div>
  </div>
  Result:
  <div id="result">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are passing obj to the index jQuery method.
Try the below code sample for your function

```
function getIndex(obj){
var ndx=$(obj).closest(".tr").index();

$("#result").html("index: "+ndx.toString());
}
```

Comment: that gives me the index of the .tr, but I want the index of the child .td inside of the .tr.